# Usage of the word "wenn"

Tags: word-usage, conjunction

*Wenn* can either mean *when* or *if*, but my question is, doesn't that cause confusion? Like if you said

> Wenn ich zu deiner Party gehe...

Would this imply your attendance at the party is conditional, or would it mean your attendance is absolute and you will be there in the future? It seems like *if* and *when* have two different meanings, one is conditional and one is not.

Isn't this confusing sometimes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, *wenn* has more than just these two meanings but most times it is unambiguous. In context you will nearly always understand which one is meant.

> Wenn ich zu deiner Party gehe, bringe ich einen Salat mit.

It's obviously that it is a condition because the subordinate clause is telling about what I'm gonna do if the part of the main clause will be true. With this subordinate clause the temporal meaning makes no sense at all.

You can try to replace *wenn* with *falls*:

> Falls ich zu deiner Party gehe, bringe ich einen Salat mit.

The second use of *wenn* is a bit ambiguous:

> Ich sage dir Bescheid, wenn ich losgehe.

Try to replace it with *sobald* and *falls*:

> Ich sage dir Bescheid, sobald ich losgehe.
>
> Ich sage dir Bescheid, falls ich losgehe.

It's most likely temporal meaning (*sobald*) because the combination of *falls + losgehen* is untypical. (you would rather say *falls ich gehe*). In very few cases it would be possible, though.
So, in general both could be possible and if so the speaker should replace *wenn* with *sobald* or *falls* or we need more context.

> Ich gehe morgen zur Party. Ich sage dir Bescheid, wenn <sub>(sobald)</sub> ich losgehe.
>
> Ich weiß noch nicht, ob ich zur Party gehe. Ich sage dir Bescheid, wenn <sub>(falls)</sub> ich gehe.

The next temporal meaning of *wenn* express repetition:

> Wenn ich zu einer Party gehe, nehme ich (immer) Geschenke mit.

Here are two things important. First that you used *immer (always)*. The second point is the plural of *Geschenk*. Without *always* and without plural it would be a condition:

> Wenn <sub>(Falls)</sub> ich zu einer Party gehe, nehme ich ein Geschenk mit.

Adverbs of time (*always*, *never*, *sometimes*) and the use of plural like that (without article or personal pronoun) indicate that this refer to a regular action (*Whenever I go to a party*)

Note the difference if there is a personal pronoun:

> Wenn ich zu einer Party gehe, nehme ich meine Schwester mit.

Because of the personal pronoun the meaning of the sentences changes. *Wenn* is the condition that must be true, otherwise the subordinate action won't happen. But when you add *immer* to this sentence you are back in the temporal meaning (Whenever you do A, you also do B).

The next *wenn* means *although*:

> Wenn ich auch müde war, bin ich zur Arbeit gegangen.

Here the important word is *auch*. The combination *wenn auch* (or *auch wenn*) is literally *even if/even though*.

*Wenn* can also express a wish:

> Wenn wir doch nur gewonnen hätten.

Without *doch nur* it would be a condition (*Wenn wir gewonnen hätten, wären wir nicht abgestiegen*), but adding *doch*, *nur* or both to a condition you express that that is a wish. You still can add as subordinate clause what had happen if your wish(the condition) were fulfilled. Usually you add *dann* or *so* to the subordinate clause:

> Wenn wir doch nur gewonnen hätten, so [or dann] wären wir nicht abgestiegen.

And last but not least:

> Er schaute mich an, als wenn er mich nicht verstanden hätte.

In combination with *als* or *wie* you describe in the subordinate clause what you've mentioned in the main clause. You do that with a comparison: He looks at me *as someone looks like when he don't understand* (Note: this is not the literally translation, just what it expresses)

Comment: Great answer, not least because despite my very limited language skills, I think I understood most of it.

Comment: _"Er schaute mich an, als wenn er mich nicht verstanden hätte."_ -- that's widely used, but it's a terrible form of slang. The correct German wording is "als ob". Also, "Ich sage Dir bescheid, _falls_ ich losgehe" means as much as "I do not intend to go, but if I do, I'll tell you (presumably when I leave)." OTOH, "Ich sage Dir bescheid, _wenn_ ich losgehe" means "I'm planning to go (though it might be unsure when), but I'll tell you when I leave".

Answer (score 4):

A more philosophical answer:

you ask whether there is room for confusion between the temporal *wenn* and the conditional *wenn*... well there is at times. The disambiguation techniques have been mentioned by the others already. But it can be argued that having just one word makes sense as you can see *if* and *when (future)* as the same thing from different perspectives

*Wenn* is used whenever you have to refer to a point in time and an event that is NOT 100% certain. This is the case in conditional, be it in past or future. But it is also the case in future. You can't be certain that something WILL happen, thus there is a degree of uncertainty to it.
Hence, there is a continuum between mere future and conditional and there occasions in the middle between the poles are ambiguous in German AND in English.

> If/when I find a penny in the street, I just ignore it.

When you talk about the past, 100% certainty is provided. Thus *wenn* is not working there, and you have to use *als*.

For a detailed look with examples you can read my [blog article on *wenn*](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/meaning-wenn/)

Answer (score 1):

Wenn can be confusing, if its conditional meaning doesn't arise from the context. In this case, you can say "falls" or form a conditional from the sentence predicate, as in "Sollte ich zu deiner Party kommen, ..." or "Würde ich zu deiner Party kommen, ..."