# Is it "wenn" or "falls"?

Tags: grammar

If I want to say, *If I want to say*, do I simply say, *Wenn ich will sagen*?

Or do I have to use *falls* instead of *wenn*: *Falls ich will sagen*?

Or can both *wenn* and *falls* be used in this context?

I know a [similar question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5840/wenn-vs-falls) has already been asked, but mine is about *usage*, not just *grammatical theory*, as is the other question. Thus said, I do not consider this to be a duplicate question.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what your question is about, if not what has been asked in the other question. - Anyway. *will* must be behind *sagen* ;) - And in your case, both are correct, *wenn* and *falls*.

Comment: @Em1 My question is, I think, quite straightforward: I simply want to know which one is the correct version for _If I want to say_. Is it _Wenn ich will sagen_ (with _wenn_), or _Falls ich will sagen_ (with _falls_)?

Comment: @indoxica: As Em1 already pointed out, the word order is wrong. Apart from this, both _wenn_ and _falls_ are possible, but _Wenn ich sagen will_ is more natural.

Comment: @chirlu OK. But why _sagen will_? In my textbook, this inversion is said to take place only with double infinitives: _Das hat er nicht sagen wollen_.

Comment: @indoxica The inversion takes place because of the conditional *wenn*. It's not related to having more than one infinitive. *Falls* and *vorausgesetzt, dass ...* induce inversion too.

Comment: @c.p. OK, all clear now. I hope no one's pissed off with my question, but there's still so much that I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To those answers to the question to which you've linked I'd add my own: I would definitely use *wenn*. I'd use *falls*, however, if I'm listing many hypothesis an the like, just in order to not repeat the same word many times. *Falls* tends to sound a little more formal.

> Wenn ich *red squirrel* auf Deutsch sagen will, wie buchstabiert man dieses Wort?
>   *Eichhörnchen*

If one sets a scale from 1 to 5, being *1: rarely used*, and *5: used all the time*, the use of *wenn* is is [5](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wenn) (d.h. sehr häufig) and the use of *falls* is [3](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/falls). The links are to Duden.

Answer (score 0):

"Wenn" means "if" of course. I would tranlate "falls" as "in case."

"Wenn" is the "general" term that is almost always correct in these contexts. I would reserve "falls" for "special cases."

"Wenn ich sagen will," is correct.

You don't have to use "falls" instead of "wenn": "Falls ich sagen will".

You can use "falls" for emphasis. The connotation is, "In case I want to say..." But that is not the normal or common usage.

Comment: Generally speaking, you hit close to home. However, I'm not sure if I completely agree with 'emphasis'. It depends on what you really think of that. I think a good point would be to relate to 'hypothetical situations'. If that's what you meant by 'emphasis', I agree with you.

Comment: Actually, it was already bothering me since the question came up: It sounds odd to me to use "falls" in this context at all. Whenever I want to make sure I'm talking about a hypothetical situation I'd say "Mal angenommen ich wollte [whatever I wanna say] sagen" or "Nehmen wir mal an, dass ich sagen möchte, dass [whatever I wanna say]". But again, technically, both *wenn* and *falls* are correct.

Comment: Also falls ich jemals 'falls ich sagen will' sagen wöllte, würde ich genau diese Worte benutzen : )
We can often think of some context where even strange constructions make sense. But I agree, 'falls' sounds more hypothetical to me.

Comment: @Em1: "In case" basically refers to a hypothetical.